# Formatting column output in Java

Tags: java

I have the below output from a loop in java, I would like to know as to how to set the gap between the columns so the output looks neat.

```
Name[Last,First]:Cruise, Tom     Movie:MI    Year:1990s     
Name[Last,First]:Hanks, Tom     Movie:Cast Away     Year:2000s
```

I want the Movie and year to be aligned along the same line. I have used three methods getName() , getMovie, getYear() to obtain data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use the tab character, If i remember right it will make it align nicely

\t

or Learn the printf, which is a shortcut for String.format();

```
System.out.printf("%12s%12s%n",hand1,h…
```

% = entity

s = String var placeholder

12 = spaces

%n = system independent line-end return

Answer (score 1):

Try to use format() or printf() method of the String class.